# To get all the nodes connected to a super node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have started learning cypher query for using graphical database. How should i get the values of all the nodes related to a super node. I am trying out the following query in console but its not working:

```
start a=node(2) match (a)-[:TYPE*]<-(node) return node;
```

node(2) is the super node. and the relation by which all other nodes are connected to a super node is TYPE.
How should i correct my query.?

Error : SyntaxException: expected -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're representing the relationship wrong, try

```
start a=node(2) match (a)<-[:TYPE*]-(node) return node;
```