# Most efficient way to get all connected nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, directed-graph

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425157/to-get-all-the-nodes-connected-to-a-super-node-in-neo4j) shows how to get a list of all nodes connected to a particular node via a path of known relationship types.

As a follow up to that question, I'm trying to determine if traversing the graph like this is the most efficient way to get all nodes connected to a particular node via *any* path.

My scenario: I have a tree of groups (group can have any number of children). This I model with IS_PARENT_OF relationships. Groups can also relate to any other groups via a special relationship called role playing.  This I model with PLAYS_ROLE_IN relationships.

The most common question I want to ask is `MATCH(n {name: "xxx") -[*]-> (o) RETURN o.name`, but this seems to be extremely slow on even a small number of nodes (4000 nodes - takes 5s to return an answer).  Note that the graph may contain cycles (`n-IS_PARENT_OF->o`, `n<-PLAYS_ROLE_IN-o`).

Is connectedness via any path not something that can be indexed?

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

As a first point, by not using labels and an indexed property for your starting node, this will already need to first find ALL the nodes in the graph and opening the PropertyContainer to see if the node has the property name with a value "xxx".

Secondly, if you now an approximate maximum depth of parentship, you may want to limit the depth of the search

I would suggest you add a label of your choice to your nodes and index the name property.

Comment: Thanks for the hints re: index on name.  I've implemented that now.

I'm a little confused - it seems to me that connectedness is such a fundamental property of nodes in a graph.  I understand neo4j supports billions of nodes.  How do 4000 nodes in a relatively sparse graph make it choke :(

Comment: @NeilGarb Neo4j can support big amount of nodes in graphs, from store and traverse perspective. But if you wan to get anwsers for your questions, you should be clever about how to ask them. Doing full database traverse - is always bad thing and should be avoided. That why labels & indexes exist. This allows Neo4j to optimize query and execute it using limited dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Use  label, e.g. `:Group` for your starting point and an index for `:Group(name)`

Then Neo4j can quickly find your starting point without scanning the whole graph.

You can easily see where the time is spent by prefixing your query with `PROFILE`.

Do you really want all arbitrarily long paths from the starting point? Or just all pairs of connected nodes?

If the latter then this query would be more efficient.

```
MATCH (n:Group)-[:IS_PARENT_OF|:PLAYS_ROLE_IN]->(m:Group)
RETURN n,m
```

Comment: I want a unique list of nodes that the starting node is connected to, connected by any path (:IS_PARENT_OF and :PLAYS_ROLE_IN could technically then be combined into :CONTAINS or something similar).  Since asking the question I've found that using traversals gives me an answer much more quickly.  Perhaps cypher's not the correct approach?