# Fastest way to get all nodes under a specified starting node

Tags: neo4j, directed-graph

I have a query that has been working for awhile, but as my graph has grown has seriously slowed down:

```
MATCH p1=(n2)-[*0..]->(n3)-[r4]->(n5)
WHERE (id(n2) = 123456 // Fill in starting node ID
  AND all(r6 in relationships(p1) WHERE (NOT exists(r6.value1) OR r6.value1 = r6.value2) // Add some constraints on the path
  ))

RETURN id(n3),n3.constr,r4.constr,type(r4),id(n5),n5.constr,n5.value // Things about n3,r4,n5, n3 may be the starting node
```

Unfortunately, there are various node labels and relationships under my starting node, and I want to return information about them so I can't constrain my query any further on those pieces. I can quickly get my starting node since I have its ID, but I can't find a quick way to get everything underneath the starting node.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563056/most-efficient-way-to-get-all-connected-nodes-in-neo4j?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) asks the same thing, but without any real answer other than to add label constraints which I can't do. Since I know I have a tree structure (and want all nodes under a starting node), is there a faster way to perform this query? Is this something I should write in the Traversal API (if so, what would that look like)?

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing I don't understand in your query.
Why have you done this `(n2)-[*0..]->(n3)-[r4]->(n5)` and not just this `(n2)-[*0..]->(n5)` ?

Moreover I don't see any constraint on the last node of your path. Normally this node is a leaf, so it's better to express it like this :

```
MATCH p=(root)-[*]->(leaf)
WHERE NOT (leaf)-->()
RETURN p
```

With this kind of query, you are only searching all the path between the root and the leafs. It's much more faster than to search all the path in your tree.

And to go one level deeper, If you want the best performances, you should use a graph traversal. Take a look at APOC with the `apoc.path.expand` procedure : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths

Comment: On your first question, there is information encoded on the edges of the path that I need to return. You can't do a variable length path and name it anymore, so this is the best way around that that I could come up with. It also encodes the variable length earlier, so each `(leaf)` you have defined isn't guaranteed to be a leaf. This returns a row for every step through the tree.

Comment: No, but can iterate over the rels or nodes of the path => `last(rels(p1))`

Comment: Is it possible to apply my first pattern against a path `p` after capturing it quickly?

Comment: like that I don't know, just give the full query and we will see

Comment: Edited into the original question